# VB 2008- runtime issues

Tags: vb.net

This is my program code....

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim adult As Decimal
    Public Function getadult(ByRef adult As Decimal) As Decimal
        Return adult
    End Function
    Public Function setadult(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
        value = adult
    End Function
    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call setadult(adult)
        TextBox1.Text = adult

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim adult As Decimal
        Call getadult(adult)
        MsgBox("the rate for adults is " & adult)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

When i enter a value into the textbox and press the "set" button it resets to 0. please help me

Comment: Was there a question in there.

Comment: that was the question.. how do i correct this runtime issue.?.... u need more details ?

Comment: I don't see any `runtime issue`.  You have not described what is going wrong.

Comment: uhm.. i enter the value in the textbar... and i click set... then the value in the textbar resets to 0 .. here is a picture ... im kinda new here.. jus trying out stuff ... so forgive me if im a little idiotic.. .http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/fv5t.png/

Comment: you programm does actually nothing at all but display an unset var (adult)

Comment: In the future (as well as now), telling us what your code is doing doesn't tell us where the problem is.  You need to tell us what it's doing in relation to the expected results.

Comment: @user217219 Are you even reading the answers?

Comment: You really need to pay more attention to your VB.NET language book.  Learn how to use a Property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function setadult(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
        **value = adult**
    End Function
```

should be..

```
Public Function setadult(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
        **adult = value**
    End Function
```

AND

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        **Dim adult As Decimal** <<<< Remove this
```

But I don't really get it why you are using two functions to set and get the value of adult. Either set it direct or maybe use a property.
For ex.

```
Public Function getadult(ByRef adult As Decimal) As Decimal
        Return adult
    End Function
```

this will just return the value you passed to the the function O.o

Maybe this is what you want to achieve:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim adult As Decimal

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        adult = CDec(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MsgBox("the rate for adults is " & adult.toString())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is a ticketing software.... i need to store the value entered in the textbox and use it for future forms ..

Comment: i want the user to set the prices for the tickets for the session..cause u know the rates are variable. .. thats why i used 2 different get and set functions

Comment: That's not a question that's a requirement. Is your current question, why you always get a 0 answered or not? If Yes accept an answer aand post a new specific question if not then you need to expand your question

Comment: eh.. okay i will create another thread

Answer (score 1):

adult no receipt value.  TEST Edit button 1 click call setadult(textBox1.text).

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim adult As Decimal
    Public Function getadult(ByRef adult As Decimal) As Decimal
        Return adult
    End Function
    Public Function setadult(ByVal value As Decimal) As Decimal
        value = adult
    End Function
    Public Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call setadult(textBox1.text)

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim adult As Decimal
        Call getadult(adult)
        MsgBox("the rate for adults is " & adult)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```